# Finding global matches inside a pattern

Tags: python, regex

If I have a pattern like this: (https://regex101.com/r/cR0aG8/12)

```
Product:.*?(.*?),.*?ReqID:
```

I assume(d) that

```
Product.*?(.*?),.*?ReqID:
```

would find `Toys`, `Books`, `Clothes` individually with G(lobal) on since to my (somewhat newbie) eye it is looking for ANY match that has `Product:` and any string ending in a comma before it and any string ending in `ReqID:` after it.

But as you can see by the regeg101 global-on gets the exact same result as global-off; the very first ,. Is there a way to structure this so the regex says just that (any string preceded by `Product:` and a `,` and followed by a `ReqID`?

Essentially I need to gather all values before or after a `,` that are bordered by the start/end pattern.

Comment: This isn't something that should be done using regexes alone. What language are you working in? (add a language tag to your question).

Comment: You formulated it correctly - grab all between the start/end pattern and then split with `,` (or with `/\s*,\s*/` pattern). What is your regex flavor?

Comment: `it is looking for ANY match that has Product: and any string ending in a comma before it and any string ending in ReqID: after it.`

I think it should include Radio no?

Comment: Not in capturing group @A.Lau

Comment: @revo `Essentially I need to gather all values before or after a , that are bordered by the start/end pattern.` That, to me, seems like he also wants to capture Radio. Just because his regex didn't include it doesn't mean he doesn't want it. You have to remember, that this poster is not very familiar with the language.

Comment: *would find Toys, Books, Clothes individually* I can't see any *Radio*. If you like to put words into poster's mouth that's OK but even if poster vouch for you, your proposed RegEx is not fine at all. @A.Lau

Comment: @revo You are correct on that, I figured I'd solve the larger problem first (grab all the values before comma) and solve the last and easier problem (,.*?ReqID) separately.

Comment: I updated my answer but since you added Python tag to your post it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create separate groups:

```
Product: (.*?), (.*?), (.*?), (.*?) ReqID:
```

To match these words. You don't even need `?` for this pattern.

This is a sed for multiple patterns:

```
$ cat t1
Product: Toys, Books, Clothes, Radios ReqID:
Product: Toys, Books, Clothes, Radios ReqID:z
izProduct: Toys, Books, Clothes, Radios ReqID:

$ sed -e '/^Product:.*ReqID:$/ s/\(\w\+\)\(,\| \)/REPLACE\2/g' < t1
Product: REPLACE, REPLACE, REPLACE, REPLACE ReqID:
Product: Toys, Books, Clothes, Radios ReqID:z
izProduct: Toys, Books, Clothes, Radios ReqID:
```

It looks for line starting with `Product:` and ending with `ReqID:`. For each line it matches `\(\w\+\)\(,\| \)`

Comment: And what if the number of groups is dynamic?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sed version will match multiple patterns. However, not sure what OP wants to do with that. If just simple replace then it is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PCRE engine (like your demo is made on it) or any of .NET, Java, Ruby or Perl regex flavors then use start match from end of previous one token `\G`:

```
(?:Product:|(?!\A)\G)(\s+\w+),
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/hG6gP8/3)

### Update

Based on new requirements:

```
(?:Product:|(?!\A)\G)\s*(\w+)(?:,| \w+:)
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/hG6gP8/4)

Comment: Your one misses the last one 'Radio'. Change to this: `(?:Product:|(?!\A)\G)(\s+\w+)[^:]?`

Comment: If you read original post carefully you will see *Radio* shouldn't be caught.